# C++ (Visual Studio 12), threads issue (AfxBeginThread)

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have some problem that seems to be very simple at the first sight, but still have no clue how to resolve this :(

I have lots of objects of, en example, class A & B. Both of them have function OnWork(), that has While () cycle inside, and when this 'while' find necessary condition, it breaks, and function OnWork() exits.

Moreover, I have threads, 1 for each object. Each thread control object' current state and when OnWork() is finished, this thread instantly kills object and than destroyes itself.

And now, the problem: inside the OnWork(): While() cycle these object must communicate with each other, sending some data. Here's example:

```
void                OBJECTS::OBJECTS_REGISTRY::OBJECT_EYE::Work() 
                    {
                        while (Source)
                        {
                        Source->DataAccept((void *) &Scan());
                        };
                    };
```

... where 'source' is a pointer to another object, that current object keeps as an attribute of its own. The idea was, that while another object exists, while cycle wouldn't be broken and necessary data would be sent without any obstacle. But when it comes to reality, the working process is going somehow like this:

1. 1 process checks 'while(Source)' and enters loop.
2. 2 process (straight after 1st) releases source (kills it), making a
   pointer, that was just checked by process # 1, 'wrong'.
3. 1 tries to send some data to non-existing object (logically throwing
   an exeption).

Threads must know only about 1 'child' object that they control. Object, that belongs to 1 process, knows about 2nd, because it depends on him, but 2nd object doesn't know about 1st.

Question is: how can i make one process forcefully execute this part of code, or lock 'Source' resource, while 'while' loop is active, so exeption won't appear?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is what mutexes are for.

Comment: Yes, I tries mutexes, but they wouldn't help( You see, ordinarily mutexes are created in the function-thread, and not in the function, where thread doesn't even enter. Thread just wait until this function exists. And it can take a VERY long time.

Comment: Do I understand you right that you have a mesh/grid of objects communicating with each other? Further, you have threads attached to each object pushing notifications or calling methods on connected objects, right? Now, my question is why do you need multiple threads and why does a "finished" object immediately destroy itself?

Comment: In my case objects simulate the real world. When you 'ask' a couple of people do smth, they won't do that in a row, one after another - they will try to do it simultaneously. When function 'OnWork' is finished, that means that you 'disattached' one device from another. Like usb flash memory and PC port. Meaning that when PC's powered down, USB won't get any sygnal from it anymore. In my case it's the same, for I'm trying to emulate that.

Comment: You could use shared_ptr since the source is not owned by a single entity. BTW, threads are expensive and don't scale well beyond a dozen or two.